# Elementor, all button on admin bar blocked

Tags: elementor

maybe it's normal but i can click on the button of the admin bar when i edit a page with elementor.

[image]

do you have the same thing, or no admin bar ?

Thanks a lot for your help

I try to contact elementor support, but they want access to my website, it's not an option for now, for security reasons.

I just want to know if you have the same thing or a fix ?